# Calculating a location coordinate a certain distance from another coordinate

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, cllocation

I have a `CLLoctionCoordinate2D` and I want to figure out what the points are a given distance away from it.  For an example, lets use 100 miles.  So I want to computer the point 100 miles to the north, south, east, and west of it.

East and west are pretty easy.  I converted both coordinates to `MKMapPoints` and used `distanceInMeters`*`MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(latitude)`.  This works fine for east and west because the latitude is constant.

However, this does not work for north and south.  To the north, it underestimates and to the south it underestimates (because `MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude` is changing as you move).  How could I compute these points for the north and south?

Comment: Can't you loop and check the real distance with CLLocation distanceFromLocation: method? It shouldn't be too costly in computer cycles.

Comment: I considered that, but I was hoping to find something a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 60 nautical miles per degree of latitude.  This is also true for longitude, but at the equator only.  To calculate the distance in longitude in nautical miles, multiply the distance in degrees longitude * 60nm * cos( latitude in radians ).

Do the calculations of your new points (100 miles north, 100 miles south, etc.) in lat lon, not MKMapPoints, then convert your lat/lon (CLLocationCoordinate2D ?) points to MKMapPoints.

Answer (score 0):

Lines of latitude are always a constant angle apart, as measured from the earth's core that's kinda their point. So what you need to do is work out how far apart in terms of miles they are, an then use that to get 100 miles north/south and then get the map points for that. The formula for the distance at the earth's surface will be online somewhere, probably in metres or kilometres.